# Gimpfu Plugin is not starting

Tags: python, plugins, gimp, gimpfu

I am currently trying to write my own plugin for Gimp.It's my first time and also my first lines in python so be gentle with me. The code is used to make my live easier creating Liveries for DCS. For that it needs to be able to find a layer by name and make it visible/invisible (In my case countrty flags). Also, not implemented yet, I want to change text from text layers.

*added afterwards
Detailed Description:
The end Goal ist to change the paint scheme for a plane in a Filght Simulator called "DCS".
The developer gave us access to texture templates.
These come with different base layers and layer-groups which need no changing.
in there I added my own layer-group which contains all my layers and layer-groups.
The script should make it easy to switch between a High-Visibility and a Low-Visibility paint scheme.
(Not implemented yet) This should be easier to achieve by hiding respective "Low Vis", "High Vis" layer-groups.
Also I wanted to make it possible to personalize the paint scheme with a Name, Callsign and a choosen Flag.
Name and Callsign have no textlayers yet and aren't implemeted.
There will be a flag on each side of the aircraft canopy (left, right).
Each flag has their own layer and there are 200+ of them.
Their layer-group structure would be "WA"/"Flag + Callsign"/"Flags Right", "Flags Left".
In their layer-group I want to make only the by input choosen Flag visible.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gimpfu import *

def ui_callsign(image, drawable, flag_var, vis_var, name_var, callsign_var):
    pdb.gimp_message("main function call")

    flag_list = ["ad", "ae", "af", "ag", "ai", "al", "am", "ao", "aq", "ar", "as", "at", "au", "aw", "ax", "az", "ba", "bb", "bd", "be", "bf", "bg", "bh", "bi", "bj", "bl", "bm", "bn", "bo", "bq", "br", "bs", "bt", "bv", "bw", "by", "bz", "ca", "cc", "cd", "cf", "cg", "ch", "ci", "ck", "cl", "cm", "cn", "co", "cr", "cu", "cv", "cw", "cx", "cy", "cz", "de", "dj", "dk", "dm", "do", "dz", "ec", "ee", "eg", "eh", "er", "es", "et", "fi", "fj", "fk", "fm", "fo", "fr", "ga", "gb", "gb-eng", "gb-nir", "gb-sct", "gb-wls", "gd", "ge", "gf", "gg", "gh", "gi", "gl", "gm", "gn", "gp", "gq", "gr", "gt", "gu", "gw", "gy", "hk", "hm", "hn", "hr", "ht", "hu", "id", "ie", "il", "im", "in", "io", "iq", "ir", "is", "it", "je", "jm", "jo", "jp", "ke", "kg", "kh", "ki", "km", "kn", "kp", "kr", "kw", "ky", "kz", "la", "lb", "lc", "li", "lk", "lr", "ls", "lt", "lu", "lv", "ly", "ma", "mc", "md", "me", "mf", "mg", "mh", "mk", "ml", "mm", "mn", "mo", "mp", "mq", "mr", "ms", "mt", "mu", "mv", "mw", "mx", "my", "mz", "na", "nc", "ne", "nf", "ng", "ni", "nl", "no", "np", "nr", "nu", "nz", "om", "pa", "pe", "pf", "pg", "ph", "pk", "pl", "pm", "pn", "pr", "ps", "pt", "pt", "pw", "py", "qa", "re", "ro", "rs", "ru", "rw", "sa", "sb", "sc", "sd", "se", "sg", "sh", "si", "sj", "sk", "sl", "sm", "sn", "so", "sr", "ss", "st", "sv", "sx", "sy", "sz", "tc", "td", "tf", "tg", "th", "tj", "tk", "tl", "tm", "tn", "to", "tr", "tt", "tv", "tw", "tz", "ua", " ug", "um", "us", "uy", "uz", "va", "vc", "ve", "vg", "vi", "vn", "vu", "wf", "ws", "xk", "ye", "yt", "za", "zm", "zw" 
                ]                                                                               #List of all flags
    pdb.gimp_message("created list")            
    for x in flag_list:                                                                         #go through list one by one
        pdb.gimp_message(x)
        if x == flag_var:                                                                       #if at by user choosen flag:
            layer_name_right = x + ".png #1"                                                    #add ending to get right layer name
            layer_name_left = x + ".png"
            layer_right = pdb.gimp_image_get_layer_by_name(image, layer_name_right)             #find right layer by layer name
            layer_left = pdb.gimp_image_get_layer_by_name(image, layer_name_left)
            pdb.gimp_item_set_visible(layer_right, TRUE)                                        #set right layer to visible
            pdb.gimp_item_set_visible(layer_left, TRUE)
        else:                                                                                   #all other flag layers same procedure as above but set to invisible
            layer_name_right = x + ".png #1"
            layer_name_left = x + ".png"
            layer_right = pdb.gimp_image_get_layer_by_name(image, layer_name_right)
            layer_left = pdb.gimp_image_get_layer_by_name(image, layer_name_left)
            pdb.gimp_item_set_visible(layer_right, FALSE)
            pdb.gimp_item_set_visible(layer_left, FALSE)
    
    pdb.gimp_message("end loop")
    return
    
    

register(
    "python_fu_ui_callsign",
    "Enter Name, Callsign and Flag selection",
    "Let's you easily change Name, Callsign and Flag on DCS Livery"
    "David Buergel", "David Buergel", "2022",
    "Ui Callsign",
    "Ui Callsign",
    "",
    [
        (PF_IMAGE, "image", "takes current image", None),
        (PF_DRAWABLE, "drawable", "Input layer", None),
        (PF_OPTION, "flag_var", "Flag", 0,
            ["ad", "ae", "af", "ag", "ai", "al", "am", "ao", "aq", "ar", "as", "at", "au", "aw", "ax", "az", "ba", "bb", "bd", "be", "bf", "bg", "bh", "bi", "bj", "bl", "bm", "bn", "bo", "bq", "br", "bs", "bt", "bv", "bw", "by", "bz", "ca", "cc", "cd", "cf", "cg", "ch", "ci", "ck", "cl", "cm", "cn", "co", "cr", "cu", "cv", "cw", "cx", "cy", "cz", "de", "dj", "dk", "dm", "do", "dz", "ec", "ee", "eg", "eh", "er", "es", "et", "fi", "fj", "fk", "fm", "fo", "fr", "ga", "gb", "gb-eng", "gb-nir", "gb-sct", "gb-wls", "gd", "ge", "gf", "gg", "gh", "gi", "gl", "gm", "gn", "gp", "gq", "gr", "gt", "gu", "gw", "gy", "hk", "hm", "hn", "hr", "ht", "hu", "id", "ie", "il", "im", "in", "io", "iq", "ir", "is", "it", "je", "jm", "jo", "jp", "ke", "kg", "kh", "ki", "km", "kn", "kp", "kr", "kw", "ky", "kz", "la", "lb", "lc", "li", "lk", "lr", "ls", "lt", "lu", "lv", "ly", "ma", "mc", "md", "me", "mf", "mg", "mh", "mk", "ml", "mm", "mn", "mo", "mp", "mq", "mr", "ms", "mt", "mu", "mv", "mw", "mx", "my", "mz", "na", "nc", "ne", "nf", "ng", "ni", "nl", "no", "np", "nr", "nu", "nz", "om", "pa", "pe", "pf", "pg", "ph", "pk", "pl", "pm", "pn", "pr", "ps", "pt", "pt", "pw", "py", "qa", "re", "ro", "rs", "ru", "rw", "sa", "sb", "sc", "sd", "se", "sg", "sh", "si", "sj", "sk", "sl", "sm", "sn", "so", "sr", "ss", "st", "sv", "sx", "sy", "sz", "tc", "td", "tf", "tg", "th", "tj", "tk", "tl", "tm", "tn", "to", "tr", "tt", "tv", "tw", "tz", "ua", " ug", "um", "us", "uy", "uz", "va", "vc", "ve", "vg", "vi", "vn", "vu", "wf", "ws", "xk", "ye", "yt", "za", "zm", "zw" 
            ]
        ),
        (PF_RADIO, "vis_var", "Vis", "vis_value",
            (
                ("High Vis", "high_vis_value"),
                ("Low Vis", "low_vis_value")
            )
        ),
        (PF_TEXT, "name_var", "Name", "enter Name"),
        (PF_TEXT, "callsign_var", "Callsign", "enter Callsign")
        
    ],
    [],
    ui_callsign, menu="<Image>/Filters")

main()
```

Plugin shows up in Gimp and gives me all the right options. After clicking ok it grey's out ok and cancle and nothing happens. No messages in the error console.

I'd be happy with all the help I can get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are in Ubuntu, you can start Gimp in a terminal to check for errors (this is also doable on OSX, on Windows you have to use `gimp-console`). When you do so you see this when you run your script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Gimp-dev/2.10.24/run/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 735, in response
    params.append(wid.get_value())
  File "/Gimp-dev/2.10.24/run/lib/gimp/2.0/python/gimpfu.py", line 567, in get_value
    return self.active_value
AttributeError: 'RadioEntry' object has no attribute 'active_value'
```

Since you have a single radio button widget the reason isn't hard to find, your code is:

```
        (PF_RADIO, "vis_var", "Vis", "vis_value",
            (
                ("High Vis", "high_vis_value"),
                ("Low Vis", "low_vis_value")
            )
        ),
```

... where the third argument is supposed to be the value set by default. But since `"vis_value"` isn't one of the two possible values this doesn't work. Change it to `"high_vis_value"` or `"low_vis_value"`.

Some more remarks:

- In the widget declarations you can reuse the flags list, this ensures consistency.
- Iterating the layers is likely much more efficient than instead of iterating the flags.
- You don't need the "drawable" parameter
- When you run Gimp in a terminal, `print` statements in your Python code are printed to the console, this is more efficient than using `gimp_message()`
- To handle your options gracefully, you can check [this](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Python-scripts-handling-PF-OPTION-and-PF-RADIO-choices-by-name)
- For some debugging strategies see [this](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Debugging-python-fu-scripts-in-Windows) (some of it also applies to Linux)
- To change text in a text layer use `pdb.gimp_text_layer_set_text(layer, text)`. But this assumes that the layer is still a pure text layer. If not in some cases the text info can be recovered and you can recreate a new layer using the font information of the previous layer. In all cases this can be tricky since you can have to reposition the layer if its size changed.
- I don't really know what you are doing but I have the feeling that using adequate layer groups would make things easier (you can toggle the visibility of a group)

You code with the first four suggestions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gimpfu import *

flag_list = ["ad", "ae", "af", "ag", "ai", "al", "am", "ao", "aq", "ar", "as", "at", "au", "aw", "ax", "az", "ba", "bb", "bd", "be", "bf", "bg", "bh", "bi", "bj", "bl", "bm", "bn", "bo", "bq", "br", "bs", "bt", "bv", "bw", "by", "bz", "ca", "cc", "cd", "cf", "cg", "ch", "ci", "ck", "cl", "cm", "cn", "co", "cr", "cu", "cv", "cw", "cx", "cy", "cz", "de", "dj", "dk", "dm", "do", "dz", "ec", "ee", "eg", "eh", "er", "es", "et", "fi", "fj", "fk", "fm", "fo", "fr", "ga", "gb", "gb-eng", "gb-nir", "gb-sct", "gb-wls", "gd", "ge", "gf", "gg", "gh", "gi", "gl", "gm", "gn", "gp", "gq", "gr", "gt", "gu", "gw", "gy", "hk", "hm", "hn", "hr", "ht", "hu", "id", "ie", "il", "im", "in", "io", "iq", "ir", "is", "it", "je", "jm", "jo", "jp", "ke", "kg", "kh", "ki", "km", "kn", "kp", "kr", "kw", "ky", "kz", "la", "lb", "lc", "li", "lk", "lr", "ls", "lt", "lu", "lv", "ly", "ma", "mc", "md", "me", "mf", "mg", "mh", "mk", "ml", "mm", "mn", "mo", "mp", "mq", "mr", "ms", "mt", "mu", "mv", "mw", "mx", "my", "mz", "na", "nc", "ne", "nf", "ng", "ni", "nl", "no", "np", "nr", "nu", "nz", "om", "pa", "pe", "pf", "pg", "ph", "pk", "pl", "pm", "pn", "pr", "ps", "pt", "pt", "pw", "py", "qa", "re", "ro", "rs", "ru", "rw", "sa", "sb", "sc", "sd", "se", "sg", "sh", "si", "sj", "sk", "sl", "sm", "sn", "so", "sr", "ss", "st", "sv", "sx", "sy", "sz", "tc", "td", "tf", "tg", "th", "tj", "tk", "tl", "tm", "tn", "to", "tr", "tt", "tv", "tw", "tz", "ua", " ug", "um", "us", "uy", "uz", "va", "vc", "ve", "vg", "vi", "vn", "vu", "wf", "ws", "xk", "ye", "yt", "za", "zm", "zw" 
] #List of all flags
    
suffix_R="png #1"
suffix_L="png"
    
def ui_callsign(image, flag_var, vis_var, name_var, callsign_var):
    image.undo_group_start()
    flag_searched=flag_list[flag_var]
    for layer in image.layers:
        print "Processing %s" % layer.name
        tokens=layer.name.split(".",1) # Split on "."
        if len(tokens)!=2:
            print "No dot"
            continue # Not dot in name, ignore other layers
        flag,suffix=tokens
        if flag not in flag_list:  
            print "Not a known flag"
            continue # Ignore other layers
        if flag==flag_searched and suffix==suffix_R:  # Requested flag and on the right 
            print "Recognized"
            layer.visible=True
        else:
            print "%s!=%s or %s!=%s" % (flag,flag_searched,suffix,suffix_R)
            layer.visible=False
    image.undo_group_end()
    return

register(
    "python_fu_ui_callsign",
    "Enter Name, Callsign and Flag selection",
    "Let's you easily change Name, Callsign and Flag on DCS Livery"
    "David Buergel", "David Buergel", "2022",
    "Ui Callsign",
    "Ui Callsign",
    "*",
    [
        (PF_IMAGE, "image", "takes current image", None),
        (PF_OPTION, "flag_var", "Flag", 0,flag_list),
        (PF_RADIO, "vis_var", "Vis", "vis_value",
            (
                ("High Vis", "high_vis_value"),
                ("Low Vis", "low_vis_value")
            )
        ),
        (PF_TEXT, "name_var", "Name", "enter Name"),
        (PF_TEXT, "callsign_var", "Callsign", "enter Callsign")
        
    ],
    [],
    ui_callsign, menu="<Image>/Test")

main()
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the informative answer.   

After adjusting a little everything is running and I get a textfile with the console outputs (using Windows).
The code is working but is seeing layer-groups as layers and does not look "into" them.
unfortunatly I don't really understand the "image.undo_group_start()" / "end" commands 
and can't find a fitting command in the Python Procedure Browser.

Thank to you, I got a much better understanding now and don't want to waste your time. 
If you'd have some source with more infos on gimp commands it would be very helpful

Comment: If you don't do the undo_group(), each modification in your script is an undo step, so to undo your script you would have to use many Ctrl-Z. With undo-group your script is undone with a single Ctrl-Z. You have to check if a layer is a group: `if isinstance(layerOrGroup,gimp.GroupLayer):`. For the doc, see [this](https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/).

Comment: If this answered you question, please consider "accepting" it (checkmark next to the votes), this marks the answer as valid and shows others that the question has a workable answer.